# .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet not working as expected in AspNetCore.Odata

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

i have Aspnetcore API using AspNetCore.Odata 7.5.12

when i hit https://localhost/beta/$metadata
i get the following response

```
<EntityType Name="Recipient">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="ObjectId"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="ObjectId" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="DisplayName" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="PrimarySmtpAddress" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="RecipientTypeDetails" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Alias" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="LastModifiedTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset"/>
<Property Name="ArchiveStatus" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="ArchiveDatabase" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="ArchiveGuid" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="EmailAddresses" Type="Collection(Edm.String)"/>
<Property Name="RecipientType" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="City" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Company" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CountryOrRegion" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Department" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Version" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="FirstName" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="LastName" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="LitigationHoldEnabled" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
<Property Name="Office" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="OwaMailboxPolicy" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Phone" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="PostalCode" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="RetentionPolicy" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="SharingPolicy" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="StateOrProvince" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Title" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="UMEnabled" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
<Property Name="UMMailboxPolicy" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="ExternalEmailAddress" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Capabilities" Type="Collection(Edm.String)"/>
<Property Name="Members" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute1" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute2" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute3" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute4" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute5" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute6" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute7" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute8" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute9" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute10" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute11" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute12" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute13" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute14" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="CustomAttribute15" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="DistinguishedName" Type="Edm.String"/>
</EntityType>

<EntitySet Name="Recipient" EntityType="Test.Recipient"/>

<Function Name="GetRecipientsIC" IsBound="true">
<Parameter Name="bindingParameter" Type="Collection(Test.Recipient)"/>
<ReturnType Type="Collection(Test.Recipient)"/>
</Function>
```

In side my function i am returning response like this

```
IList<Recipient> RecipientList = responseMessage.ResponseData as IList<Recipient>;
return this.StatusCode((int)statusCode, RecipientList);
```

I have verified that data is correct and RecipientList is valid and when an api call is made the code is able to execute return statement.

The response i am getting this:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://localhost/beta/$metadata#Recipient","value":[{
```

which leads to http2 error

i am not able to understand why i am not getting correct response

Comment: Hi @suraj, what is your detailed error? For you shared response, do you only get the truncated json string? Also, it is better for you to share the asp.net core version and enough code to reproduce your issue.